# Loop over array and create a Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a list of values in a array, I need to create a query based on that

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

url = http://localhost:3000/site/query=("ID:"+ 1 + "ID:" + 2 + "ID:" + 3)
```

the number of ID increases based on values in an array.

I tried creating a for loop and than add i for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    url = http://localhost:3000/site/query=("ID:"+ x[i])
  }
  if (i === 1) {
    url = http://localhost:3000/site/query=("ID:"+ x[0] + "ID:" + x[i])
  }
}
```

I cannot create multiple if blocks because the "i"value can be dynamic and there could be many values in array

Comment: So the desired pattern is `ID:ID:ID:ID:` without a separator character?

Comment: I need to build a query, for example if I have two values in array [1,2], the url will be http://localhost:3000/site/query=("ID:"+ 1 + "ID:" + 2)

Comment: So the result would be `ID:1ID:2` ?

Comment: yes, if there is only one number, only one ID will be there

Comment: thanks for taking time and looking into this talpar

Answer (score 2):

I mean, if that's really what you want, you can just join the array.

```js
var x = [1];
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/site/query=ID:'+x.join('%20OR%20ID:')
console.log(url);

var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/site/query=ID:'+x.join('%20OR%20ID:')
console.log(url);
```

%20 is space encoded for urls.

Comment: answer should be ID:1 OR ID:2 OR ID:3 OR ID:4 OR ID:5